Getting firestore subdocuments
I have a firestore database with documents inside a users documents. for example
/users/{uid}/purchases
/users/{uid}/devices

I would like to fetch all the names of these documents using the firestore rest API. for example list documents under /users/{uid}/.
How do I go about it?

It sounds like you're trying to list subcollections, not documents.  In your example, {uid} looks like the ID of a document. Document are directly nested under other documents.  Please edit the question to be more clear what you're trying to do (perhaps showing actual data), and what you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.

what I'm actually trying to do is, user data is stored in a document with their user ID, now a user can have multiple collections in their document, a get request to the api only returns the fields and not the subcollections. Is it possible using rest ? or should I find a client to do this

It is not possible to get a list of collections with either the client-side SDKs or with client-side tokens from the REST API.

So you'll either have know what collections exists already (typically by storing a marker value in their parent document for each such subcollection, e.g. hasPurchases/hasDevices), or you'll have to use an Admin SDK in a trusted environment (or the REST API with the OAuth2 token of a collaborator on the Firebase project with the right IAM permissions) to get the list of subcollections (as shown in the links).
